# I need help on XSL path directory

Tags: xml, xslt

C: drive is my current xsl path

When I use this XSL code to get my XML file it works fine

```
<xsl:variable name="Path">
<xsl:value-of select="'file:///C:'"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

but when I use this XSL code to get my other XML file it doesn't work

```
<xsl:variable name="Path1">
<xsl:value-of select="'file:///E:'"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: your code is just setting a variable to a string value. For the variable it doesn't care if it is a file or the name of a person, it is just text. Where is that variable used?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown us. The problem is elsewhere.

By the way, this is very inefficient:

```
<xsl:variable name="Path">
<xsl:value-of select="'file:///C:'"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

you should use

```
<xsl:variable name="Path" select="'file:///C:'"/>
```

because there's no need to create a new XML document when you only want a simple string.